# In JQuery, trouble with removing tags in table correctly

Tags: jquery

I have the following page:

```
<div style="display: inline">
<input type="button" id="txt" value="Add TextBox" style="" />
</div>
<br />
<h1 id="headerBuilder">Build the New Control</h1>
<table id="tblControls" width="50%"table>
<br/>
<input type="button" id="btnProcessControl" value="Generate New" />
```

In my JQuery code I create two table rows, each with two table data cells.

```
function displayTxtBuilder() {
    $("#tblControls").contents().remove();

    var $MaxLengthQuestion = $('<label />').text('Set the Max Length Value:');
    var $MaxLengthInput = $('<input/>').attr({ type: 'text', id: 'maxlength', size: '3', maxlength: '3', value: 'max' });
    var $BodyQuestion = $('<label />').text('Set the initial value of the textbox:');
    var $BodyInput = $('<input/>').attr({ type: 'text', id: 'body', size: '3', value: 'body' });

    $("#tblControls").last().append(
                $TableRow.append($TableData.append($MaxLengthQuestion)).append($TableData2.append($MaxLengthInput))
            );

    $("#tblControls").last().append(
                $TableRow2.append($TableData3.append($BodyQuestion)).append($TableData4.append($BodyInput))
            );
}
```

I thought that the code

```
$("#tblControls").contents().remove();
```

would remove all the contents of tblControls, but instead I see the $TableRow.append being repeated everytime I run displayTxtBuilder.  Not sure why its doing only repeating the first append.  On the other hand, if I replace

```
$("#tblControls").contents().remove();
```

with

```
$("#tblControls").remove();
```

none of the `.last().append()` rows show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `empty()`

```
$("#tblControls").empty();
```

Comment: Vote on this guys!! My query is working, but im not jQuery specialist and my answer was not professional.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $("#tblControls").find("*").remove();
```

Comment: `empty()` like I suggested. `find('*').remove()` is 88% slower. http://jsperf.com/all-selector-vs-empty